# Can not create launcher on desktop

Tags: launcher, panel, ubuntu-mate

I can add this to my panel as a launcher.

But I can not create the launcher on my desktop?

This is in my desktop directory, but it does not show on my desktop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=mate-panel-launcher
Icon[en_US]=mate-panel-launcher
Exec=/home/andy/bin/SysLog.sh
Name[en_US]=SysLog
Name=SysLog
```

Another strange thing is I can not move the launcher in my panel like the others?

Any ideas?

```
cd /home/andy/Downloads
# Send syslog to text file
cat /var/log/syslog > syslog.txt
# using geany, open syslog at the end
geany -l 10000000 syslog.txt
rm /home/andy/Downloads/syslog.txt
```

Comment: Question quite unclear. In addition, solutions may depend on the desktop environment you use.

Comment: Why would you create such a file? Syslog is already a text file, sometimes very large, so why copy it to syslog.txt? Why edit syslog.txt? The whole thing makes no sense. Please explain.

Comment: The script shows me the end of syslog so I check to see if certain events have occured. @heynnema

Comment: @vanadium What is unclear? I can not create the launcher on my desktop.

Comment: "I can add this to my panel as a launcher." "this" is not well defined for one thing. "The launcher"? What launcher? Can we assume you use the standard Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu-Mate. In my version, you can right click desktop and create a launcher. That launcher starts a program, runs a script etc. Am using the Mate desktop.

Comment: To check syslog, view the file directly, or `grep` to find certain events, or install `glogg` to easily review the syslog. Your script can only cause problems.

Comment: I am used script for years with no problems. :-)

Comment: What if syslog is 10G and you only have 5G left on your HDD/SSD? Boom. Either view syslog directly, or, as I suggested, try `glogg`. Or use the `tail` command.

Comment: I have a 2 Tb hard drive. tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog

Comment: Did you look at `glogg`?

Comment: Yes. It takes longer to see the info I want. @heynnema

Comment: `glogg` has a built-in search/grep function. How are you currently looking/viewing/greping for the info that you want?

Comment: This only lists the last 110 lines tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog I am looking to see that ) CMD (/home/andy/bin/emptytrash15.sh) ran. @heynnmea

Comment: grep 'emptytrash15.sh' /var/log/syslog